# Bootstrap-rating not visible on https

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, grails

I am using bootstrap-rating in my Grails application.Its working properly on local machine but not visible on https after deploying on client server. We are using relative path while including on gsp as shown below:

href="/css/bootstrap-rating.css", src="/js/bootstrap-rating.min.js"

Error shown on browser console is like `"Mixed Content: The page at 'https://test.test.com/account/searchAccount/23' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://test.test.com/static/js/bootstrap-rating.min.js"`
How to solve this issue?

On GSP, I've done following,

```
<link href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'bootstrap-rating.css')}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir: 'js', file: 'bootstrap-rating.min.js')}"></script>

<input type="hidden" class="rating rating-gly" value="${lifeTime}" data-readonly  />
```

Comment: Try `href="./css/bootstrap-rating.css", src="./js/bootstrap-rating.min.js"` by preceding `.` to the path

Comment: you don't show us, how all of this ends up in your generated html.  please show us, what ends up in the browser (use your devtools).  this could as well be a wrong `grails.url` and absolute urls generated. and as a sidenote, it's common to use `//css/...` (double leading slash) to make the browser use the same protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you have mixed content HTTP and HTTPS. This is not allowed. 
Try to use `createLink(uri:'/css/bootstrap-rating.css')` 
That should create a correct relative path. Or use grails asset-pipline. I allways use asset-pipline and it works fine for both HTTP and HTTPS.